# Why neovim plug treesitter don't work on WINDOWS?

Tags: neovim, treesitter

I'm trying to use the treesitter plugin of neovim on windows, but it doesn't work,
error as follows:
`c.so is not a valid Win32 application`
`python.so is not a valid Win32 application`

I did some research which says perhaps there are something wrong with the compiler,
but i don't known how to fix the problem, anyone help me?

Comment: how do you get those so files? The shared library on windows should be dll not so. This seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something messed up during compilation of grammar files, to try to fix this issue, do following steps:

- Ensure that you have appropriate compiler installed and treesitter is configured to work with it:

  - I use *clang* compiler that is being installed together with [llvm](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html)
  - Make sure that *clang* is in *PATH*. Try running

    ```
    clang --version
    ```

    it should output something like this:

    ```
    clang version 13.0.0
    Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
    Thread model: posix
    InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin
    ```
  - Make sure that treesitter configured to use *clang*, for that in your treesitter configuration you have to set following:

    ```lua
    if vim.loop.os_uname().sysname == "Windows_NT" then
       require('nvim-treesitter.install').compilers = { "clang" }
    end
    ```

    Note: I use here *if*, because I use same configuration files both on windows and on linux environments.
- Reinstall treesitter plugin (do it according to your plugin manager)

  - Make sure that old grammar files are no longer there:
    Example path for *packer* plugin manager:

    ```
    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter
    ```

Reinstall required parsers with `:TSInstall` command, that is probably it.