# NeoVim Treesitter Config failed to run

Tags: neovim, treesitter

I am new to Neovim and I was installing NVChad. When I opened a .lua file I got this error...

```
Failed to run `config` for nvim-treesitter

Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: C:\Users\USER-PC\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\parser\lua.so is not a valid Win32 application.^M


# stacktrace:
  - C:/Program Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:98 _in_ **add**
  - C:/Program Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/languagetree.lua:98 _in_ **new**
  - C:/Program Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:61 _in_ **_create_parser**
  - C:/Program Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:131 _in_ **get_parser**
  - C:/Program Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:459 _in_ **start**
  - lua/plugins/init.lua:86 _in_ **config**
  - lua/core/utils.lua:111
  - vim\_editor.lua:341
```

I don't know what wrong. I tried :TSUpdate, :TSInstall c, :TSInstall cpp, but they all pass and update as normal.

What's wrong and how do I fix this?

I don't know what wrong. I tried :TSUpdate, :TSInstall c, :TSInstall cpp, but they all pass and update as normal.

I also tried

```
:TSInstall c help lua vim
```

and got the following error

```
Could not load parser for lua: "Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: C:\\Users\\USER-PC\\AppData\\Local\\nvim-data\\lazy\\nvim-treesitter\\parser\\lua.so is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n"
```

What's wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74225678/why-neovim-plug-treesitter-dont-work-on-windows/74320900#74320900